# При добавлении значения в реестр в конце значения ставятся три точки

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

```cpp
char* ccometa = new char[cometa.length() + 1];
    strcpy(ccometa, cometa.c_str());
    TCHAR Tccometa[512];
    _tcscpy(Tccometa, ccometa);
    HKEY hKeys;
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS == RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "SuperData\\command", 0, NULL, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, &hKeys, NULL))
    {
        RegSetValueEx(hKeys, _T(""), 0, REG_SZ, (BYTE*)Tccometa, sizeof(Tccometa));
        RegCloseKey(hKeys);
    }
```

P.s. проект сделан в visual studio 2019,используется многобайтовая кодировка.
И если не делать такие манипуляции:

```cpp
char* ccometa = new char[cometa.length() + 1];
    strcpy(ccometa, cometa.c_str());
    TCHAR Tccometa[512];
    _tcscpy(Tccometa, ccometa);
```

То в реестр будут записываться непонятные символы. Сам string cometa:

```cpp
std::string appdata = getenv("APPDATA");//получить папку appdata
std::string cometa = appdata + "\\" += userd4t4.dat;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sizeof(Tccometa)` всегда возвращает 512, потому что данная функция возвращает размер памяти, выделенной ВСЕЙ данной переменной, вне зависимости, сколько из этих байт занято полезной информацией, а сколько пустует.

Предлагаю Вам использовать `(strlen(Tccometa) + 1) * sizeof(TCHAR)` вместо этого. Данная конструкция вернёт длину записываемой строки + 1 символ в байтах. Дополнительный символ использован, чтобы учесть символ конца строки (в документации к `RegSetValueEx` написано, что он должен быть учтён). Умножение на `sizeof(TCHAR)` используется, т.к. байтовая длина `TCHAR` может меняться.

Таким образом, Ваш код примет следующий вид:

```cpp
char* ccometa = new char[cometa.length() + 1];
strcpy(ccometa, cometa.c_str());
TCHAR Tccometa[512];
_tcscpy(Tccometa, ccometa);
HKEY hKeys;
if (ERROR_SUCCESS == RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "SuperData\\command", 0, NULL, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, &hKeys, NULL))
{
    RegSetValueEx(hKeys, _T(""), 0, REG_SZ, (BYTE*)Tccometa, (_tcslen(Tccometa) + 1) * sizeof(TCHAR));
    RegCloseKey(hKeys);
}
```

И кстати, если уж Вы используете `TCHAR`, используйте функции работы со строками и сами строки, устойчивые к изменению типа `TCHAR`. `TCHAR` может определяться как `char` или как `wchar_t`. Во втором случае у Вас сломаются `strcpy` и `char* ccometa = new char[cometa.length() + 1];`, работающие только с `char`, но не с `wchar_t`. В таком случае я посоветовал бы Вам везде перейти к `TCHAR`, а `strcpy` заменить на `_tcscpy`. `std::string` тогда заменится на `std::basic_string<TCHAR>`. Возможно придётся произвести ещй ряд замен. Чтобы проверить, будет ли всё работать в случае, если `TCHAR` определится как `wchar_t`, просто добавьте `#define UNICODE` в начало программы. А вообще, лучше подумайте, так ли Вам сильно нужен этот `TCHAR`.